# Teams Integration with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I want to be able to send messages from a chat in Microsoft Teams to Microsoft Dynamics **manually** (as a new record, i.e. as a case). I have had a look at using Flow however it only includes triggers when a new channel message is created or when you are mentioned in a channel message. These are very specific and will not fit our needs.

Has anyone done this before or have any suggestions as to how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Logic App. The [teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/teams/) connector has support for Get Messages.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, i will look into this

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are asking, this is possible by using a custom action [like in Slack](https://slack.com/apps/collection/actions?utm_source=in-prod&utm_medium=inprod-more_message_actions_button-more_actions_menu-click).

This is [not yet available](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams-AMA/Adding-custom-actions-to-team-conversations/td-p/226552) in MS Teams.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I feel like there is still a lot Microsoft can do in terms of integrations between their different platforms. It is like the basic requirements are there and now they need to work on a few more of the advanced requirements..

Comment: @NDevBrad completely agree. we have to understand that MS is rolling out the minimum viable product and then next feature set thru continuous delivery model.. may be their prioritization & deadline is not matching the customers need :)

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest another workaround:

Set up a bot that you can integrate in your Teams channel.
From there you can feed the bot with information you want him to post to Dynamics.